# jQuery send class as POST parameters

Tags: ajax, jquery, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to send class as post ajax parameters.

my class :

```
  public class PageInput
    {
        public string ActionName { get; set; }
        public string Controller { get; set; }
        public int CountPage { get; set; }
        public int CountRecordInPage { get; set; }
    public KeyValuePair<string, short> No { get; set; }

    }
```

ajax code :

```
$.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetPageNumbers", "MyClasses")',
        data: '@Model.PageInput',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
```

action :

```
 public ActionResult GetPageNumbers(PageInput pageInput)
    {
        return PartialView("_PagingNumbers", pageInput);
    }
```

doesn't working. But why?

When data are received by the actionResult are empty!!But the data are correct before sending.

Comment: The default `$.ajax()` type is `'GET'`, so you'd need to set that to `'POST'` if you're expecting only posted data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create an object within your JavaScript code and send that across instead:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetPageNumbers", "MyClasses")',
    data: {
        ActionName: '@Model.ActionName',
        Controller: '@Model.Controller',
        CountPage: @Model.CountPage,
        CountRecordInPage: @Model.CountRecordInPage,
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

You also need to add the `[HttpPost]` attribute to your controller action

Comment: this is a good. but how to send property "No" ? property "No" is a KeyValuePair.

Comment: No. question is Updated.

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that you aren't posting to your `url`

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetPageNumbers", "MyClasses")',
    data: '@Model.PageInput',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
        console.info(data);
    }
});
```

Now it will post.

Comment: i changed " type: 'POST'" but doesn't working. why? Empty class are posted

Comment: i'll need more information than it doesn't work why. Give us something to work with, errors etc

Comment: Error does not happen.But the data is sent empty

Comment: cool, see updated code and open up your console, `F12` and tell me what it responded with. Also, which browser are you using?

Comment: error : the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found).I'm using Chrome

Comment: and what was the url that was output from: `url: '@Url.Action("GetPageNumbers", "MyClasses")'` have a look at the page source. Good stuff about chrome :) You could even look in the network page and clear the current things displayed in it. When you click to do the ajax u'll see the url its trying to reach.

Answer (score 0):

you should use following pattern:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("GetPageNumbers", "MyClasses")',
    data: {"PageInput.CountPage": "@Model.PageInput.CountPage", "PageInput.CountRecordInPage":"@Model.PageInput.CountRecordInPage" },
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

I think It will work for you. While Ajax post it is necessary that you should use name of the class in AJAX post parameters.